# Солитер и солитёр

Tags: омонимы

Солитер — это большой бриллиант (понятно, от слова "sole", да?). А солитёр — извиняюсь, глист. Разница не даже не букве, а в звучании этой буквы, а смысл совсем разный. Почему так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И то и другое слово пришли из французского [языка](http://www.vasmer.slovaronline.com/%D0%A1/%D0%A1%D0%9E/12457-SOLITER). Во французском слово "solitaire" означает одинокий, отшельник. Слово это также стало обозначать крупный бриллиант вправленный без других камней и ленточного червя cestoda, также предпочитающего одиночество, но уже внутри кишечника.

В русском языке, скорей всего под воздействием грамматики, звучание слов разошлось, и из [sɔlitɛʀ] вышло солитер и солитёр.

Comment: А причины для расхождения?
Иногда встречаются попытки произнети Ё так где его нет и не может быть во французском (гренадЁр, афЁра), но они нормативными не становится (Кузнецов как контраргумент не принимается).

>[солит'УОр]   
  
????
При почти абсолютном моей незнании языка такая транскрипция какжется по меньшей мере странной.

Comment: @behemothus, спасибо за замечание, транскрипцию исправил.

 За ответом почему солитёр - это норма русского языка, а афёра нет, обращайтесь к Ушакову, я ответа не знаю.

Во французском у слова солитер тоже есть такие же [значения](http://slovari.yandex.ru/solitaire/fr-ru/#lingvo/)

Answer (score 0):

Брилльянт, понятно. Из французского, а там никакого Ё в помине нет: solitaire.
Ну а глист, вроде, напрямую с латыни. Не могу найти написание, но похоже, что там может быть что-то похожее на Ё.

Comment: Для справки: в латинском языке, в отличии от французского, ничего похожего на сочетание -тё- нет.

Comment: ГЛАСНЫЕ И ДИФТОНГИ.
...
oe -- произн. как немецкое [ö] или французское [œ].
...
"фонетика латинского языка".

Но я не это имел в виду. 
Как пишется солитер - (глиста) на французском, Вы можете сказать?

Comment: В латинском языке не было мягкого "Т" и сочетание -тё- [т'о] в латинских словах невозможно. Есть правда слово "toechobates", но оно заимствовано римлянами с греческого, да и русское заимствование перевели как "тихобат".